# combine multiple activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I was wondering if I can combine multiple activities the way I can combine multiple layout using layoutinflator ?

I mean you can combine multiple layout into one layout using inflator .

Can I do something like that with activities ?

Say I have three activities and I have their respective layouts . Now I want to combine all three activity so that they show up on the screen side by side.
Is that possible ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html + C:\android\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\compatibility\v4 for using it on Android < 3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No its not possible because in Android each screen is an Activity.

An Activity is an application component that provides a screen.

Comment: so that means if I have to combine then I have to rewrite the complete code manually ? .. Thanks

Comment: yes if you want to add three layout in one activity then you can use <include></include> tag to add the layout of your activity in xml file.